# Cxf exception mapper not being invoked

Tags: java, spring, exception, cxf

I have created a custom exception and I have an exception mapper that I want to be invoked when my exception is thrown, so that I can return proper http return codes and messages, but for some reason it doesn't work for my exception.

Here is the relevant code

My Exception class:

```
public class MyException extends ApplicationRuntimeException
{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyException ()
    {
        super();
    }

    public MyException (String message)
    {
        super(message);
    }

    public MyException (String message, ErrorCode errorCode)
    {
        super(message, errorCode);
    }

    public MyException (Throwable t)
    {   
        super(t);
    }

    public MyException (String message, Throwable t)
    {
        super(message, t);
    }

}
```

My exception mapper class

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<Exception>
{
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(Exception exception)
    {
        //code
        return response;
    }
}
```

cxf-config

```
<jaxrs:server id="serviceId" address="/">
        <jaxrs:providers>
            <bean class="com.package.MyExceptionMapper"/>
        </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

This is essentially what my code is like, is there anything I'm missing or any other information I need to provide in order to resolve this issue?

The exception and exception mapper are located in two different projects, but I don't think that should matter because they are both in the class path.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check if on MyException the toResponse() method gets executed at all or not?

Comment: the toResponse() method never gets executed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is your full CXF, you are missing the service bean in this server being executed.

The provider is tied to the service and will only execute for the service beans also defined in the server.

Aside from that everything looks fine so I would check and make sure your exception is really being thrown.

Comment: I do have a serviceBean defined and I've found that when the exception is thrown outside the service bean the exception mapper is not being invoked, while if it is thrown inside the bean it is being invoked. How would I change it so the exception mapper is always invoked?

Comment: To expand on my last comment, the exceptions that the exception mapper is not getting invoked for are getting thrown from a <jaxrs:inInterceptor> bean

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are doing. You have a serviceBean that has a say @POST annotation on a method. That method is throwing an exception of type MyException. You have written an ExceptionMapper to translate that exception to a specific response. This is the use case for ExceptionMapper specifically. You write a Provider (ExceptionMapper) for a jaxws server that deploys the service bean. The interceptor framework is at a different level of operation, depending on what type it is. You never mentioned other interceptors, so please provide the entire scope of what you are doing in the ?

Comment: I'll try and explain this the best that I can.

I have a serviceBean with @POST annotation on a method. When someone sends a post request there is an inInterceptor that is run and validates some things. If an exception is thrown in there, then the exception mapper is not invoked. If I throw an exception within the method itself it works.

Does that clear it up?

Comment: Absolutely, you are using the exception mapper wrong in this case. You need to manually catch the exception in your interceptor and return the response you want, or better yet, write an aspect that does it (talk about proxy madness). You can however intercept on the outbound and do the same thing, but the ExceptionMapper is for those exceptions thrown out of your service classes specifically. Easiest way to handle this, in my opinion, if you want a standard response for this exception is to simply handle it in the interceptor

Comment: Thank you, will go for that approach.

Answer (score 0):

The exception mapper just handle exceptions thrown by service beans.

One option in this case is to throw a new WebApplicationException(Throwable, Response) in which the response should be built the same way as what've been done in your exception mapper.

If you are trying to do some validation, creating a custom message body reader is one good option, I think. By doing this, inside the message body reader, you also be able to access to other providers/exception mappers.

Good luck!